# jQuery race condition with external scripts loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I am trying to conditionally load the slick slider jQuery library only if there are more than a certain number of slides. Otherwise, I do not want to use the slider.

It works fine if I don't append the script to the head tag, and instead run it inline where this script happens on the page. However, once it executes as written below, it complains slick() is not a function.

How do I make sure slick finishes loading first, without using require.js?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var slideCount = $('div.recipe.slide').length;

        if(slideCount > 4) {
            $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css">');
            $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.css">');
            $('body').append('<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"><\/script>');
        }

        $('.image-slider').slick({
            arrows: true,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 2000,
            dots: false,
            mobileFirst: true,
            slidesToShow: 4,
            responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: 1,
                    settings: {
                        arrows: false,
                    },

                    breakpoint: 479,
                    settings: {
                        centerMode: true,
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

USE Script if this loaded like this:

```
 /*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
   function load_js_file(_url, _callback){
        _callback=_callback||function(){};
        _url=_url||'';
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = _url;
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.onload = function() {
          _callback();
        };
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);       
   }

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/


   function load_css_file(_url, _callback){
        _callback=_callback||function(){};
        _url=_url||'';
        var script = document.createElement('link');
        script.href = _url;
        script.type = 'text/css';
        script.rel  =  'stylesheet';
        script.onload = function() {
          _callback();
        };
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);       
   } 

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/    




   $(document).ready(function () {

        var slideCount = $('div.recipe.slide').length;
        if(slideCount > 4) {

            load_css_file('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css', function(){
                    load_css_file('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.css', function(){
                          load_js_file('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js', function(){


                             $('.image-slider').slick({
                                         arrows: true,
                                         autoplay: true,
                                         autoplaySpeed: 2000,
                                         dots: false,
                                         mobileFirst: true,
                                         slidesToShow: 4,
                                         responsive: [
                                                       {
                                                         breakpoint: 1,
                                                         settings: {
                                                              arrows: false
                                                         },

                                                         breakpoint: 479,
                                                         settings: {
                                                               centerMode: true
                                                         }
                                                       }
                                                     ]
                             });

                          });
                    });              
            });


        }

    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but as noted. it does not work if the script is appended to the head. It must run in place where it's at on the page. It gives slick() is not a function. The ready event is calling slick() before it is loaded.

Comment: add function $('.image-slider').slick(...); to onload funcrion

Comment: Thanks. Seems to work inline with the functions intact, but the moment I move the functions to an external js file that is referenced above the document.ready, it fails to work. Also fails to work if the entire thing is loaded via an external file... slick() is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of [jQuery's getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) which provides a callback for when the script finishes loading, then you can run your slick code (which is now wrapped in a function)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var slideCount = $('div.recipe.slide').length;
  slideCount = 5;
  if (slideCount > 4) {
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css">');
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.css">');
    $.getScript("//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js", function() {
      callSlick();
    });
  }

  function callSlick() {
    $('.image-slider').slick({
      arrows: true,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 2000,
      dots: false,
      mobileFirst: true,
      slidesToShow: 4,
      responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 1,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
        },

        breakpoint: 479,
        settings: {
          centerMode: true,
        }
      }]
    });
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function